# readfile return open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, download, readfile

I have create one function in Codeigniter controller for download file, here is code for that.

```
function download_example($file_name) {
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_name);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile(base_url().'download_example/'.$file_name);
}
```

But after download in file show **403 Forbidden error** like this.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: 
>   readfile(http://example.com/download_example/example.txt): failed to
>   open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
>
> Filename: controllers/controllers.php
>
> Line Number: 371

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to something like:

```
readfile(dirname(__FILE__).'/download_example/'.$file_name);
```

If it is local file and current PHP script's directory is same as `download_example` directory. Change to match your system. Also make sure that file does exists and that user where web server is running has permission to access this file.

Comment: Thanks Zamrony, it's work for me i have use  **readfile(FCPATH.'/download_example/'.$file_name);**

Comment: @Zamrony P. Juhara, you nailed it (after three edits, but... )here's my upvote

Answer (score 2):

Using `base_url()` will get you the http address of the file, like `http://example.com/download_example/file_name`, but it's a better idea to use the server sistem path like `C:\path\to\site_dir\download_example_dir\file_name`.

I personally use something like this:

`dirname($this->input->server('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/download_example_dir/file_name'`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with your script, but with the resource you are requesting. The web server is returning the "forbidden" status code.

It could be that it blocks PHP scripts to prevent scraping.

You should probably talk to the administrator of the remote server.